# How do I connect a PC with my Apple Cinema 27" Display

Tags: display, displayport

I have a PC that has displayport, DVI, and HDMI out. I would like to connect this to an Apple Cinema 27"  Display. The apple display only has a mini displayport male connector coming out (it is not thunderbolt).

The problem is that there aren't many adapters out there that has a *female* mini displayport connector. The only thing I've managed to find is this: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B003LGOWNQ/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003LGOWNQ)

But that only supports 720p.

Is there an adapter or set of adapters that will let my PC take full advantage of the apple display?

Comment: What makes you say it only support up to 720p?  In the spec on the link you provided: "Supports Mini DisplayPort output; Supports resolution of up to 1920x1200".

Comment: The two bullet points below that:

Comment: 1920 x 1200 @ 60Hz on 24-inch Apple LED Cinema Display*
1280x720 @ 60Hz on 27-inch iMac and Apple LED Cinema Display*

Answer (score 2):

You need a DisplayPort male to mini DisplayPort female adapter. It looks like StarTech makes [one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812200691).

Comment: BTW, I can't recommend StarTech as a brand because I've had a lot of trouble with their mini DisplayPort male to HDMI female adapters, but any port in a storm, I guess.

Comment: StartTech is hit or miss on a lot of their products unfortunately. :/

Comment: Any other suggested brands then for this adapter?

Comment: @jimothy Sorry, no.